# How to make an active navbar link when it shows its page using react-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, navbar

I'm using react bootstrap and react in the development of my portfolio app, however, I just need one small detail to add and can't find the right method to do it.

I need to make the link on the navbar switch color depending on the page, for instance if I'm on the home page, "Home" on the navbar should be different in color, and so on.

This is the last thing i need to finalize my code.

if you want to check the whole repository here it is: https://github.com/awadbilal/portfolio

This is my navbar code:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Container, Navbar, Nav, NavDropdown } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import "./style.css";

function NavBar() {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  // const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();

  // const changeLanguage = () => {
  //   if (i18n.language === "en") i18n.changeLanguage("ar");
  //   else i18n.changeLanguage("en");
  // };

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar className="navBarSection mt-3" collapseOnSelect expand="lg">
        <Container>
          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
          <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
            <Nav className="me-auto pt-3 pb-3">
              <Nav.Link eventKey={1}>
                <Link to="/" className="underline">{t("nav.home")}</Link>
              </Nav.Link>
              <NavDropdown.Divider />
              <Nav.Link eventKey={2}>
                <Link to="/works" className="underline">{t("nav.works")}</Link>
              </Nav.Link>
              <NavDropdown.Divider />
              <Nav.Link eventKey={3}>
                <Link to="/education" className="underline">{t("nav.education")}</Link>
              </Nav.Link>
              <NavDropdown.Divider />
              <Nav.Link eventKey={4}>
                <Link to="/contact" className="underline">{t("nav.contact")}</Link>
              </Nav.Link>
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
          {/* <div className="languageButton" onClick={changeLanguage}>
            {i18n.language === "en" ? "AR" : "EN"}
          </div> */}
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
    </>
  );
}

export default NavBar;
```

And here is how it should look:

[image]

Comment: @Henry Ecker i tried your method it still doesn't work, i'm not sure what is causing this problem to happen, i tried multiple methods, but i still can't find an answer.

Comment: I just edited your post. Perhaps you meant to respond to the user who answered your question below?

Comment: @Henry Ecker oh yes, i'm sorry i'm still new to posting in stackoverflow, i only used to check other questions before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Import the `useLocation` hook from React Router then you can make some dynamic classNames:

```
// ...
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
// Import useLocation hook
import { Link, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

function NavBar() {
  const location = useLocation(); // once ready it returns the 'window.location' object
  const [url, setUrl] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    setUrl(location.pathname);
  }, [location]);
  // ...
  return (
    // ... Just a dumbed down example:
    <Nav>
      <Link to="/" className={"underline" + (url === "/" ?" active" : "")}>Home</Link>
      <Link to="/projects" className={"underline" + (url === "/projects" ?" active" : "")}>Projects</Link>
      <Link to="/contact" className={"underline" + (url === "/contact" ?" active" : "")}>Contact</Link>
    </Nav>
  );
}
```

And so on. Do this for each Link and add the path name, and it'll work like expected.

Obviously in your CSS you need to create a class to show the active link, e.g.:

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

### Update

Now with React Router 6's [`<NavLink>`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/nav-link) component, you can easily implement this by reading the `isActive` argument passed to a function inside the `className` prop:

```
// ...
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
// Import useLocation hook
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'; // import the NavLink component

function NavBar() {
  // ...
  return (
    <Nav>
      <NavLink to="/" className={({ isActive }) => "underline" + isActive ? " active" : ""}>Home</Link>
      <NavLink to="/projects" className={({ isActive }) => "underline" + isActive ? " active" : ""}>Projects</Link>
      <NavLink to="/contact" className={({ isActive }) => "underline" + isActive ? " active" : ""}>Contact</Link>
    </Nav>
  );
}
```

This makes our works a lot more flexible and not hard-coded.

Comment: i tried your method it still doesn't work, i'm not sure what is causing this problem to happen, i tried multiple methods, but i still can't find an answer.

Comment: Specifically what doesn't work? Did you add the CSS? Do you fully understand the code? (So you can adapt it correctly.)

Comment: Thank you, for some reason it didn't work before, after i tried it again today, i checked at first it didn't work, i stopped react app from running and then initialized it again and now its working, not sure what caused it not to work before re-running the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class NavLink extends React.Component {
    render() {
        var isActive = this.context.router.route.location.pathname === this.props.to;
        var className = isActive ? 'active' : '';

        return(
            <Link className={className} {...this.props}>
                {this.props.children}
            </Link>
        );
    }
}

NavLink.contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object
};

export default NavLink;
```

And use it as given below in your component:

```
...
import NavLink from "./nav_link";
.....

<nav>
   <ul className="nav nav-pills pull-right">
      <NavLink to="/">
         <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> <span>Home</span>
      </NavLink>
      <NavLink to="about">
         <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></i> <span>About</span>
      </NavLink>
   </ul>
</nav>
```